# HTML email: @media queries that work on mobile and Outlook

Tags: css, outlook, media-queries

I'm coding up HTML for an email that would be viewed both in Outlook and in mobile devices. I'd like to use tables for Outlook (I need a multi-column set up), and single column divs for mobile devices (or anything < 400px).

I'm trying to do this with @media queries, and I know Outlook's CSS support is extremely shoddy, but I'm wondering if anybody knows a hack that can make Outlook "ignore" the @media query for < 400px, and apply styles for the >400px part. I tried this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px)
{
    .mobile-email { background-color:green; }
} 

@media (min-width:500px) 
{
    .mobile-email {  background-color:red;}
}
```

The trouble seems to be that Outlook ignores both. Is there any way I can make this sort of a thing work in Outlook?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe this site: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/ will help you understand wat and wat not to do. Meaning there is no hack, it will work because it is supported, or not.

Answer (score 3):

In all honesty I'd steer well clear. HTML emails are a horrile horrible business. Adding media queries into the mix is asking for trouble.

Blackberrys don't support media queries for a start...

http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/media_queries_in_html_emails

Outlook barely even does standard CSS since it [switched it's rendering engine to MS Word's](http://litmus.com/blog/outlook-2013-still-powered-by-word-now-available-for-email-testing).

[Check out this site about email standards](http://www.email-standards.org/) support for more information. I still use inline styles and tables in HTML emails as it's still the most consistent way of getting results (which in 2013 is pretty terrible)

Comment: Thanks SpaceBeers. Yes I'm fully aware of the limitations, but I don't have much choice. For the emails you compose, how do you ensure they scale down well for iPhone/Android email clients?

Comment: @Raj - Keep the template very simple and then do it % tables. It's horrible but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The best practices would be to do inline css for background color. Your writing a class that does not work a cross the border. Some devices like script this way some like script this way. For example when you a responsive email that calls for a hidden: border; most devices and browser will do as the media queries call. However Android gingerbread does not do a hidden  border. An iphone will do hidden the border. Outlook 2013 will do hidden the border but yahoo won't do it. For what your doing background colors for Outlook 2007 and 2010 need to have that inline You would want it to read Text here

Am hoping that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Outlook still does not support media queries, but you can specifically target Outlook to hardcode the CSS with this:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style type="text/css">
.mobile-email { background-color: red; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```